# How to add a random port in the Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring-Dalston release with Wiremock for Integration tests.
I want to start a WireMock server in order to replace the cloud config configurations. So for that reason I do:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:12345", "eureka.client.enabled=false",
        "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:ingest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Application.class)
public class RssApplicationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static WireMockClassRule wiremock = new WireMockClassRule(WireMockSpring.options().port(12345));
```

but the port in the property spring.cloud.config.uri is hard-coded and I can not tell Spring to put specific(random port) for spring.cloud.config.uri

I am searching something like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:{$local.server.port}",
```

is it possible?

Comment: did you try ${local.server.port} instead of {$local.server.port}?

Comment: Yes I tried,but it is not found.